# How to add a Sprite as a Class to the scene?

Tags: swift, class, sprite-kit

I want to add a sprite to my Game Scene. But the thing is, that I want to add the sprite several times, so I wanted to make a class out of the sprite and I dont want to work with the Scene Editor

So my Class is called Passenger and this is the code for it

```
import SpriteKit

class PassengerNode: SKSpriteNode, CustomPassengerNodeEvents {

init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
    <#code#>
}  
}
```

In my Games Scene I wanted to add the class like

```
let passenger = PassengerNode()
```

But I wonder how I can set the texture within the Passenger Class? I cant figure this out? Any hints or recommendations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track with subclassing SKSpriteNode.  I have a standard template that I use when I create a SKSpriteNode subclass that looks like this.  Also, I have augmented it with a function that can be called from outside the class to change the texture to whatever you like:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class SubclassedSKSpriteNode: SKSpriteNode {
    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "whateverImage.png")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())
        userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

   // MARK: - Change Texture

   func updateTexture(newTexture: SKTexture) {
      self.texture = newTexture
   }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = (touches.first! ).locationInNode(scene!)
        position = scene!.convertPoint(location, toNode: parent!)

        print("touchesBegan: \(location)")
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = (touches.first! ).locationInNode(scene!)
        position = scene!.convertPoint(location, toNode: parent!)

        print("touchesMoved: \(location)")

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = (touches.first! ).locationInNode(scene!)
        position = scene!.convertPoint(location, toNode: parent!)

        print("touchesEnded: \(location)")
    }
}
```

Also, to add this button to your SKScene (or any other SKNode):

```
let button = SubclassedSKSpriteNode()
button.position = CGPointMake(420, 300)
addChild(button)
```

Then, if you ever want to change the texture, call:

```
button.updateTexture(newTexture)
```

HTH!

Comment: `updateTexture` is not needed, `button.texture = newTexture` works just as well, and if you need to do other things during the set, just override the property in the subclass

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks for the comment, and you are right!!  The reason I use that method in my subclasses is because I almost always do a few other tweaks at the same time, like using SKActions to rotate the sprite or scale it in some way.

Comment: @zeeple I added the Class like you did, and since then my previous methods can not access the passenger instances anymore. :?
I used to check for collisions, that worked, but they don't work anymore either... I am little bit confused now :-/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set all your properties before calling that super.init. You can create a default init() function, and set your properties, then call super.init with the texture etc.

```
class SomeSprite: SKSpriteNode {
    init() {
        let spriteTexture: SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "someImage")
        let spriteSize = spriteTexture.size()
        super.init(texture: spriteTexture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: spriteSize)
    }
}
```

You're right that you need to call `init(texture:color:size)`, since it's the designated initializer for `SKSpriteNode`. But you should be aware that you can call a designated initializer from another `init` function in your subclass, in this case the blank `init` implementation. Just set your default values and create the sprite.